Can a "hangout" mean an occasion where people hang out with each other?
hang out (v): to spend time relaxing or socializing
 hang out (n): a favorite place for spending time
Can a hangout possibly mean an occasion where you hang out with your friends or family? It's not listed in dictionaries, but sometimes there are senses that can't be found there. If it's not the case here, what's the word for this?
P.S. As for the possible suggestions, it would be preferable if they were not informal.

Given that a hangout is well-established as a place where people hang out together, you'd probably be understood if you used it to refer to a "social gathering", but the usage has no currency. But since "hanging out" with friends is an informal usage, why do you ask for alternatives that are not informal?

Thanks! An informal phrase is okay, and that was actually what I was looking for initially. But then I realized that a not-so-informal one would be more versatile and useful.

As what @FumbleFingers said, use of hangout in the sense of an outing or occasion would be understood in general.
Such usages, hangout used as an occasion, are found in M+W:

But in the summer, the sunshine and clear skies can be helpful when planning a hangout with a friend or gatherings with family.—Mariyam Muhammad, The Enquirer, 3 July 2024

More usage examples in this sense are found also in this other M+W page.
As hangout even in the sense of a place is already rather informal, its sense as an occasion (hardly found in dictionary definitions although found in usage examples) would be even more so.  It should hence be used only informally.
